# How to add a zoom option to gmap v3 on jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mobile

I am having trouble adding a default zoom number to this code as I am using a panTo function.  I am using gmap for jquery.  This is my code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').panTo(myLatlng);
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble finding the gmap for v3 plugin. Can you add a link? If you're using the [gmap for v2 plugin](http://gmap.nurtext.de/documentation.html), you could use the setCenter function instead of the panTo function: `$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').setCenter(myLatlng, myZoom);`

If the gmap vor v3 plugin exposes the v3 api, then you could make a call to setZoom after making a call to panTo.

**Updated after clarification of plugin source:**

The plugin has a built-in method for doing that: `centerAt`. You don't need to get the jQuery object with the map div, as that's a container for a DOM object, not a google.maps.Map object. I.E. it won't have a panTo method. Here's how you recenter/zoom, the way the plugin author intended (assuming myLatlng you mentioned is a google.maps.LatLng):

```
// initialize the map
$('#map_canvas').gMap(); // this can take a ton of options if you want.
```

Then later...

```
// reposition/zoom the map.
$('#map_canvas').gMap('centerAt', {
    latitude: myLatlng.lat(),
    longitude: myLatlng.lng(),
    zoom: myZoom
});
```